# Memory de-allocation: how much cpu overhead does the java environment

Tags: java, android, memory-management, opengl-es, stack

In a real-time 3d application (written using java in Android Studio and OpenGL ES, though that isn't important for this question) the frame rate started dropping significantly because per-frame operations **overloaded the heap/gc** with thread-safe `final` objects which each cast `new` objects for most operations. (E.g. adding two 3d points together created a `new` point object, discarding the old.)

Android's garbage collector quickly picks up on the massive burden in the young heap, but after the lag freezes the game temporarily. The solution was to use unsafe objects written as registers (operations modify the original points rather than casting new ones) and storing those register-like classes as fields in the parent class. The GC migrates them quickly to the old heap, avoiding any real GC overhead until the parents are recycled.

The question is, **should temporary primitives** (e.g `int i` and `float t`) **also be stored as "registers"** too to avoid java environment de-allocation every time?

The project has roughly 50 classes each with about five temporary values, 4 bytes each. They are reused roughly ten times each per frame, 30 frames per second, or **17MB per minute**. Keeping them as registers (class fields) costs only **1,000 bytes** on the stack.

Should these primitives be stored as class objects to avoid redundant re-allocation? This question is really whether releasing primitives from the stack costs a noticeable amount of CPU time.